# Add values from two textboxes and display the sum in third textbox 3 but value of 1st aor 2nd textbox show in third textbox

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3PvK.jpg)

Add values from two textboxes and display the sum in third textbox 3 but value of 1st aor 2nd textbox show in third textbox

Comment: Unclear what you try to achieve, do you want the program to add textbox1's value and textbox2's value and show the sum in textbox3?

Comment: yes but when i enter any number in 1st textbox this number automatically show in third textbox then add with 2nd number

Comment: you can use a textchanged event to let the program do this automatically when you change the text in your textbox. Put @Imad his code inside that event.

Comment: please send me any sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will automatically change your value once you alter textbox1's value

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0 && textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text));
        }
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0 && textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 && textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            textBox3.Text = textBox2.Text;
        }
        if(textBox1.Text.Length == 0 && textBox2.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            textBox3.Text = "0";
        }
    }
```

edit: treat textbox value as 0 when its empty.

This example will still error if you enter non-numeric values into the textbox.

Comment: this show error Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'

Comment: yes it gives an error when either one was empty then what i do next sir??

Comment: Updated code to handle the formatException error, excuse me for being sloppy in my coding. I've made myself an application to test this and it works now :)

Comment: now it is true but can't add number in third textbox

Comment: It didn't say you wanted to do this in your question, edit your question in order for people to answer it to your desire.

Comment: sir if we have 12 textbox then this procedure is difficult can you have other short method for 12 textboxes

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text)
```

This will do it, just enter proper number. No exception handled.

To handle exception, use Double.TryParse instead of `Convert.ToDouble`.

[Look at msdn example.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yes but when i enter any number in 1st textbox this number automatically show in third textbox then add with 2nd number

Comment: then how we add exception?